# How many values can be returned from a function?

Tags: python, function, tuples

In python you can do this:

```
def myFunction():
    return "String", 5.5, True, 11

val1, val2, val3, val4 = myFunction()
```

I argue that this is a function which returns 4 values, however my python instructor says I am wrong and that this only returns one tuple.

Personally I think this is a distinction without a difference because there is no indication that these four values are converted into a tuple and then deconstructed as 4 values.  I am unaware of how this is any different than the same type of construct in languages like JavaScript.

Am I right?

Comment: A function can only return a single object. If more than one variable is part of a return statement python will automatically pack them into a tuple. You're instructor is right -- what you're doing on the last line is known as unpacking a tuple.

Comment: The *function* itself returns a *single* tuple. How *you*, yourself specifically, *use* the output unpacks the tuple into 4 distinct values. It is impossible for a function to return more than a single value. "*I think this is a distinction without a difference*" It IS, but just in THIS specific context. The whole idea of a function is for it to be re-usable elsewhere, where you may not wish to unpack the values from the tuple for whatever reason.

Comment: `type(myFunction())` would be a good indication. Also https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement leads to https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-expression_list which tells you it's a tuple.

Comment: "*because there is no indication that these four values are converted into a tuple and then deconstructed as 4 values.*" Just because something has been abstracted away from your personal purview most absolutely does not mean that it isn't happening, does it?

Comment: It returns the 4 variables as a tuple. You are breaking the tuple up when it comes back. https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-function-return-multiple-values/

Comment: As already stated a function can only return a single object, but it can be a *container* of any number of other objects.

Comment: You can also use `ret = myFunction()`without implicitly unpacking the `tuple`, as shown by `print(type(ret))`. If it would return 4 variables, you would only get your `str` or am I mistaken?

Comment: While it surely is nice to know that this is what is happening (a single tuple return, but unpackable automatically) internally, for all intents and purposes, you can return multiple values from a function. 

I believe it's a common question to ask, especially with newer developers: how can I return multiple values? Simple answer is this.

After answering this simple question, you can then regale them with a pedantic explanation of whats really going on, if they care to listen.

Comment: @Greywire: If it's such a common question, then someone should have closed it as a duplicate by now. Otherwise the results as you describe are what happens and are appropriate for this website's Q&A format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll take a stab at this, since I think the issue here is a lack of defining terms properly.  To be completely pedantic about it, the correct answer to the question as worded is "zero".  Python doesn't return a value; it returns an object, and an object is not the same thing as a value.  Going back to basics on this one:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types

> Objects are Python’s abstraction for data. All data in a Python
> program is represented by objects or by relations between objects.

also:

> Every object has an identity, a type and a value.

A value, as defined above, is something different than an object.  Functions return *objects* and not *values*, so the answer to the question (as asked, if taken to literal extremes) is zero.  If the question had been, "How many objects are returned to the caller by this function?" then the answer would be one.  This is why defining terms is important, and why vague questions generate multiple (potentially correct) answers.  In another sense, the correct answer to the question would be five, because there's five things one might think of as "values" coming back from this function.  There's a tuple, and there's the four items inside the tuple.  In still another sense, the answer is four (as you've said) because the code flat out says **return** and then has four values afterwards.

So really, you're both right, and you're both wrong, but only because the question isn't sufficiently clear as to what it wants to know.  The instructor is likely trying to put forth the idea that Python returns single objects, which may contain multiple other objects.  This is important to know, because it contributes to Python's flexibility when passing data around.  I'm not so sure the way the instructor worded it is achieving that goal, but I'm also not present in the class, so it's tough to say.  Ideally, instruction should cover neurodiverse ways of understanding, but I'll save that soapbox for a different discussion.

Let's distill it like this in hopes of providing a clear summary.  Python doesn't return values, it returns objects.  To that end, a function can only return *one* object.  That object can contain multiple values, or even refer to other objects, so while your function can pass back multiple values to the caller, it must do so inside of a single object.  "Objects" are the internal unit of data inside of Python, and are distinctly different from the "value" contained in the object, so it's a good practice in Python to always keep in mind the distinction between the two and how they're used, regardless of how the question is worded.

Comment: Pedantic weenie for the win... :)

Answer (score 0):

Your instructor is correct.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types

> Tuples
>
> > The items of a tuple are arbitrary Python objects. **Tuples of two or more items are formed by comma-separated lists of expressions.** A tuple of one item (a ‘singleton’) can be formed by affixing a comma to an expression (an expression by itself does not create a tuple, since parentheses must be usable for grouping of expressions). An empty tuple can be formed by an empty pair of parentheses.

Applied to your example:

```py
foo = "String", 5.5, True, 11
assert isinstance(foo, tuple)
```

So you're clearly returning a single object.

Here's how the assignment expression is specified when there are multiple targets (variables on the left hand side):

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements

> Assignment of an object to a target list, optionally enclosed in parentheses or square brackets, is recursively defined as follows.
>
> > If the target list is a single target with no trailing comma, optionally in parentheses, the object is assigned to that target.
> >
> > Else: **The object must be an iterable with the same number of items as there are targets in the target list, and the items are assigned, from left to right, to the corresponding targets.**

(All emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

Python functions can return multiple values. These values can be stored in variables directly. A function is not restricted to return a variable, it can return zero, one, two or more values.

This is the default property of python to return multiple values/variables which is not available in many other programming languages like C++ or Java.

For returning multiple values from a function, we can return tuple, list or dictionary object as per our requirement.
[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/returning-multiple-values-in-python#:~:text=A%20function%20is%20not%20restricted,one%2C%20two%20or%20more%20values](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/returning-multiple-values-in-python#:%7E:text=A%20function%20is%20not%20restricted,one%2C%20two%20or%20more%20values).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).